# Remove cookies via ngx-cookieconsent

Tags: angular, cookies

im using ngx-cookieconsent and cant find how to remove/delete existing cookies in the browser.
Any ideas?

docu:
(https://tinesoft.github.io/ngx-cookieconsent/doc/index.html)
(https://github.com/tinesoft/ngx-cookieconsent)

Stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/github/tinesoft/ngx-cookieconsent/tree/master/demo

ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this library not for this purpose, but you can delete any cookies with native Javascript

```
function delete_cookie( name, path, domain ) {
  if( get_cookie( name ) ) {
    document.cookie = name + "=" +
      ((path) ? ";path="+path:"")+
      ((domain)?";domain="+domain:"") +
     ";expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
 }
}

function get_cookie(a) {
    var b = document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*' + a + '\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)');
    return b ? b.pop() : '';
}
```

Comment: You might also want to add the get_cookie function in your answer..